# Adding array to numbers from array

Tags: javascript

```
{
    "songs": {
        1: {
            "name": "bestmusic"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to add the number 2 to the array.
`songs.2 = {};` doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just use an array?

Comment: That's an object, not an array. Multiple objects actually.